# Beautiful Soup in Python is not giving me the correct number of links on the page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request

I am trying to count the number of links on a Web page using the following code:

```
import requests
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd 


webpage = "https://www.isode.com/products/index.html"


try:
    response = requests.get(webpage)
    #response.raise_for_status()
except HTTPError:
    print("A HTTP Error has occured")
except Exception as err:
    print(err)
else:
    print("The request of the webpage was a success!")

contents = response.content
contents

soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, features = "html.parser")    

a = 0
for link in soup.find_all("a"):
    if link.get("href"):
        a=a+1
        print(link.get("href")
```

My expected answer is 86 but this code is giving me 83, so I am lost about where I am going wrong?

Also, in terms of having a count variable - surely there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Why is your expected value 86?  I just counted them on the page source and there are 83 hrefs in the body

Comment: That is the solution to the exercise - so not just me going crazy then!

Comment: Like exercise for school? I'd ask your professor if the page may have changed since they checked it.

Comment: @user1558604 I actually just counted 86 - i think you forgot the sub links in the "Markets" dropdown

Comment: @user1558604 ah, it is because I am only looking for the href links whereas I want all the links!

Comment: @Sorath check my answer below and have a look here. https://i.ibb.co/mXYdHJK/Capture.png

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

links = []
with requests.Session() as req:
    r = req.get('https://www.isode.com/products/index.html')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    if r.status_code == 200:
        for item in soup.findAll('a'):
            item = item.get('href')
            if item is not None:
                links.append(item)
print(len(links))
```

Output:

```
83
```

But if you remove the condition of `if item is not None:` so you will get `86`

[image]

Deep version:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

links = []
with requests.Session() as req:
    r = req.get('https://www.isode.com/products/index.html')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    if r.status_code == 200:
        count = 0
        for item in soup.findAll('a'):
            item = item.get('href')
            if item is not None:
                if item.startswith('..'):
                    item = item.replace('..', 'https://www.isode.com')
                elif item.startswith('http'):
                    pass
                else:
                    item = (f"https://www.isode.com/"+item)
                print(item)
                links.append(item)
            else:
                count += 1

print(f"Total Links: {len(links)}")
print(f"Total None: {count}")
```